# Concatenate multiple PDF/A with different conformance levels

Tags: itext, pdfa

Is it possible to concatenate a number of pdf/a (with possibly different conformance levels: some pdf/a-1b, some pdf/a-3b ecc) into a single pdfa ?

I was thinking that using the latest level (3-a or 3b) would be ok but I get errors when validating with VeraPDF:
[image]

Here is my code (where :

```
public static byte[] CreateConformantCopy(List<byte[]> sourcePdfs)
    {
        var version = PdfVersion.PDF_1_7;
        var type = PdfAType.PDF_A_3B;

        WriterProperties wp = new WriterProperties();
        wp.UseSmartMode();
        wp.SetPdfVersion(version.ToPdfVersion());

        PdfOutputIntent oi = new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("xxx.Resources.sRGB_CS_profile.icm"));

        using (var mergedPdf = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter(mergedPdf, wp);

            using (PdfADocument newDoc = new PdfADocument(writer, type.ToPdfAConformanceLevel(), oi, new DocumentProperties() { }))
            {
                Document document = new Document(newDoc, PageSize.A4.Rotate());

                newDoc.SetTagged();

                newDoc.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name));

                newDoc.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(
                        new PdfViewerPreferences()
                            .SetDisplayDocTitle(true)
                            .SetCenterWindow(true)
                );

                PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(newDoc);

                for (int k = 0; k < sourcePdfs.Count; k++)
                {
                    using (var inDoc = PdfHelper.GetDocument(sourcePdfs[k]))
                    {
                        var numberOfPages = inDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

                        merger.Merge(inDoc, 1, numberOfPages);
                    }
                }

                newDoc.Close();
            }

            return mergedPdf.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PDF/A-1 and PDF/A-2 have several differences in the requirements. So, merging them together might not be possible. Looking on your validation errors, I think this is exactly the case. For example, the very first one is about XMP metadata. The PDF/A-2 is more strict here, and you get this error because your first file (which is probably a valid PDF/A-1) does not actually satisfy the PDF/A-2 rules.

What is possible however is to *attach* a PDF/A-1 document to PDF/A-2 one. This does not even require the use of PDF/A-3, which allows arbitrary attachments. The PDF/A-2 standard does allow attaching valid PDF/A-1 (as well as PDF/A-2 documents).

Comment: what about concatenating pdf/a files with the same conformance level ?

Comment: yes, I think this would work. One needs to be careful a bit with Metadata: (strictly speaking, the merged PDF does need a different metadata + there might be some conflicts between custom XMP schemas). Plus, if all the documents conform to Level A, then their Structure trees need an accurate merge.